# What are the main properties of the CMGs on the ISS

Tags: iss, attitude

How large (mass) are the [CMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope)s on the ISS?
What is the minimum torque they apply?
What is the maximum torque they apply?

Comment: It is helpful to show some of the research you have already done. Is there a page showing info about the CMGs that does not list this info? Then perhaps give us a link to it. Also abbreviations such as CMG are always good to define for the benefit of other readers who find this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The L-3 Communications Control Moment Gyroscopes (CMGs) used on the ISS have specifications detailed in the [L-3 CMG Control Moment Gyro datasheet](http://www2.l-3com.com/spacenav/pdf/datasheets/CMG.pdf). Here are the properties you are looking for:

> Weight 600 lb., 272 kg
>
> Maximum Output
> Torque 258 Newton-meter

It's not specified, but I see no reason why the minimum torque wouldn't be zero.